# Can I get back withholdings after losing my job?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california

If I was taxed at 120k starting January, but only worked for 4 months and don't plan on working for the rest of the year, is there anyway I can take the adjusted withholdings (40k instead of 120k salary) earlier (this month)?

Comment: If you had planned at the beginning of the year to only work 4 months in the year, you could have increased the number of allowances on your W-4 so they would have withheld less. But if you only decided to stop working in the middle of the year, there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no mechanism for a refund of withholding, other than filing a tax return, which cannot be done prior to the end of the tax year.

Comment: It's difficult to find a reference to back up this answer. The best I have been able to find is in Publication 17 (2017), Chapter 4, page 39, "Check Your Withholding", which says "If too much tax is withheld, you will lose the use of that money until you get your refund."

Comment: It's usually hard to find references for things that don't exist.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like something that should be allowed (which is why I asked), but I guess it isn't economical especially since they want you to work.

Comment: What? I pay estimated taxes, why can't I get estimated refunds? :-(